# How to free the content of a file?

Tags: java

I want to write in a file, if it exists i would like to free the content and to write from the begining of the file this the code that i use but i dont now how to do that.

```
try {
            File f = new File(testPath + "/logtest.txt");
            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();                                                                                             
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
                bw.write(text);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();
            } else {
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
                bw.write(text);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: By "free the content" do you mean overwriting the current content in the file with the new content you are about to place in?

Comment: change to new FileWriter(f,false) if you want to overwrite

Comment: when i change th boolean to false in my file i have just the last line et not all what i write

Comment: is the code above inside a loop ?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) constructor allows to specify whether you want to append to or overwrite the content:

> public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - file - a File object to write to
> - append - if true, then
>     bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

In your code, you pass `true`. Simply change it to `false`:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
```

EDIT: in case the code you gave in your question is inside a loop, here's how you should change it:

```
try {
    File f = new File(testPath + "/logtest.txt");
    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));

    for/while (...) { // your loop here
        // extract your text
        bw.write(text);
    }

    bw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exceptions...
}
```

Comment: when i change the boolean to false in my file i have just the last line et not all what i write.

Comment: It was not clear from your code snippet that this was in a loop. The solution is simply to put the lines that open and close your file outside of the loop. This way, it won't be overwritten each time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
```

the second parameter `append` in the `FileWriter` constructor you are using is a flag witch controls whether the file sould be truncated before the first write or the data writen should be appended.

[see javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will overwrite whatever was there earlier.

```
    String fileName = "foo.txt";
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try{
        fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        fw.write("haha");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not write to the file.");
    }finally{
        if(fw!=null)
            try {
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not close the file.");
            }
    }
```

If you want to append the data use

```
fw.append();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class FileClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "Hello test";

            File file = new File("D:\\filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your file deleted, because you do a `f.delete();` in a loop.

You should do a construction like this:

```
File f = new File(testPath + "/logtest.txt");
if (f.exists()) {
    f.delete();     
}
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));

while (...)
    String text = ...;

    bw.write(text);
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
```

This way you create/delete the file only once.